# Bug in GNAT Get(FRom => SomeString, Item => SomeInteger, Last => Last)?

Tags: string, input, ada, gnat

Get(TheFile, IntValue); works great with strings formatted like 16#12# to read hex values.
Shouldn't Get from a string function the same way?

I tried this, but passing 16#12# only yields 16. Pure hex, eg F8 results in an exception

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure hex is
   IntValue  : Integer;
   Last : Positive;
begin
   Put("Enter a hexadecimal string: ");
   Get(HexString);

   -- Convert the hexadecimal string to an integer
   Get(From => HexString, Item => IntValue, Last => Last);

   Put ("The integer value is: ");
   Put (IntValue, Width => 0);
   New_Line;
end hex;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Ada Language Reference Manual states:

```ada
procedure Get(From : in String; Item : out Num; Last : out Positive);
```

> Reads an integer value from the beginning of the given string,
> following the same rules as the Get procedure that reads an integer
> value from a file, but treating the end of the string as a file
> terminator. Returns, in the parameter Item, the value of type Num that
> corresponds to the sequence input. Returns in Last the index value
> such that From(Last) is the last character read.
>
> The exception Data_Error is propagated if the sequence input does not
> have the required syntax or if the value obtained is not of the
> subtype Num.

The explanation of reading a value from a file is

```ada
procedure Get(File : in File_Type; Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);
procedure Get(Item : out Num; Width : in Field := 0);
```

> If the value of the parameter Width is zero, skips any leading blanks,
> line terminators, or page terminators, then reads a plus sign if
> present or (for a signed type only) a minus sign if present, then
> reads the longest possible sequence of characters matching the syntax
> of a numeric literal without a point. If a nonzero value of Width is
> supplied, then exactly Width characters are input, or the characters
> (possibly none) up to a line terminator, whichever comes first; any
> skipped leading blanks are included in the count.

The get function works correctly.
If you want to convert a string containing an Ada hex value such as 16#12# you should use the 'Value attribute.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure convert_hex is
   Num : Integer := Integer'Value ("16#12#");
begin
   Put_Line (Num'Image);
end convert_hex;
```

Comment: Get from string uses the same rules as Get from file according to the RM. But apparently it doesn't, as Get from file yields the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that can’t be the code you ran, because you haven’t declared `HexString`. Also, what’s that `Get`?

This works as you wanted:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure hex is
   IntValue  : Integer;
   HexString : String (1 .. 16);
   Last : Natural;
begin
   Put("Enter a hexadecimal string: ");
   Get_Line(HexString, Last => Last);

   -- Convert the hexadecimal string to an integer
   Get(From => HexString (1 .. Last), Item => IntValue, Last => Last);

   Put ("The integer value is: ");
   Put (IntValue, Width => 0);
   New_Line;
end hex;
```

Comment: The first Get is just to read a string. Yes, I forgot to declare the variable in the example, but in my code it is there.

Comment: What exactly was the string returned by this `Get`? I assume you mean the one in [ARM A.10.7(14)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p14), where the number of characters read is determined by the length of the string concerned. NB, we’re arguing about the code that may or may not be on your machine. If you edit the question to show your actual code, the chance of resolving the issue will be much greater

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong when I tried this at first, but     
`Get(From => HexString, Item => IntValue, Last => Last);`  
 actually works if the string is formatted correctly - 16#ff# as an example.
Sorry about the noise and thanks for your input.